# Is it possible: {$smarty.const.$My-Variable}

Tags: php, smarty

I have many `{$var}` variables (PHP constants). And I want to see it in smarty, but `{$smarty.const.$var}` and `{$smarty.const.[$var]}` brings me an error. How can I do it? Thanks.

For example, in my template I want to see (`$var = my constant`):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{$name}" {if $smarty.const.[$name] == "1"}checked="checked"{/if} />
```

Happy Holidays!

Comment: try `{$smarty.const[$var]}`

Comment: In which scope are these "constants" ? I think with `{$smarty.const.MY_CONST}` you can actually only reach content which is defined by PHP's define (http://php.net/manual/de/function.define.php)

Comment: This is a bad practice, check the note in Smart documentation: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl#language.variables.smarty.const

Answer (score 2):

{capture assign=constantName}{$your_var}{/capture}
using: {$constantName|constant}

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
$smarty.const.[$name]
```

to

```
$smarty.const.{$name}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
{$smarty.const.`$name`}
```